# Java app: Connect to PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am attempting to connect to a postgres SQL database. Normally, I can connect by simply going to the link:

```
test.ischool.testU.edu
```

Where I connect to phpPgAdmin by entering my credentials, and then I can connect to my database, testDB, by selecting it from the side.

Here is my relevant Java code:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://test.ischool.testU.edu:5432/testDB";
    String user = "testuser";
    String pass = "testpassword";
    Connection db = null;
    try {
        db = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I receive the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port             are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I'm pretty sure I am doing something wrong. Assuming that my code is correct (which I'm sure is not the case), to connect to the database, do I need to have my .jar file inside the remote directory, or can I run it locally? Does it make a difference?

I have successfully connected to my database using the following python code (this code was inserted into the remote directly and run from there):

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=testDB user=testuser password=testpassword")
```

Comment: You mentioned you connected using the *Python* code directly on the server. Can you connect via any method -- the *psql* client, say -- via the client server where you want to run the Java code? Sounds like this may be a networking issue, or a *Postgres* server config issue that won't accept the IP you're connecting from.

Comment: I can connect using phpPgAdmin. My instructor mentioned that "it must run on the course database server.  A client-side app won’t be able to connect to the database". I believe this is the reason why I cannot get my code to work. For instance, I can use putty and type "python test.py" and it will connect to the database and do whatever. However, I'm not sure how to run a Java .jar file in the same way, even if it is already uploaded to the remote directory.

Comment: Given that instructor's limitation, as @BohuslavBurghardt mentioned in one of his comments, you'll have to run it on the server. There are a variety of ways to run the contents of a *jar* via a command line, but it depends substantially on exactly how the code was structured. I would recommend starting with [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html).

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC URL you are using is for MySQL:

```
jdbc:mysql://test.ischool.testU.edu:5432/testDB
```

use one for PostgreSQL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://test.ischool.testU.edu:5432/testDB
```

If changing this doesn't help please post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Whoops! While trying some other peoples' solutions, I copy-pasted some code and forgot to change it. Though, even with this, I get the error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: You said that you were connecting successfully to the DB using python code which runs remotely (does it run on the same server as the DB)? Also when are you connecting to phpPgAdmin it probably runs on the same server as the DB which leads me to the conclusion that the PostgreSQL server is not configured to accept remote connections. In that case there is nothing you can do except running the Java program remotely same as your python program.

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code:

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/YOURSCHEMA?user=YOURUSER&password=YOURPWD";

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);`
```

Comment: What do I put for my schema? o-o Sorry, I'm not very good at this.

Comment: Alrighty. I assume that I need to run this on the same server as the database? If so, would you have any tips on how to remotely run a jar file from a website?

Comment: from what i have understood, you have a problem connecting to your postgres db, With my code you should be able to connect to the database, at least for me it works. So, my question is what else is the problem?

Comment: I am getting this error: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." Since your code uses "localhost" with no reference to the URL at all, I think that you expect the .jar file to be on the same server as the database, right? I tried copying the .jar file onto the server and running it from there (though I believe I'm not running it correctly, as opening the .jar from WinSCP creates a local clone of the file, so it's still technically not on the remote server).

Comment: you should be able to connect to a remote db as well
try this connection:

`String url = "jdbc:postgresql://test.ischool.testU.edu:5432/testDB?user=YOURUSER&password=YOURPWD"`

Comment: check your firewall settings, maybe this port is blocked!